# Sum value based on distinct unit in array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am stuck on situation, where I have JSON response like

```
[{
    "product": "CLINISod",
    "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
    "dose": "2 acs",
    "period": "all",
    "in": "Morning"
}, {
    "product": "CLINISod",
    "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
    "dose": "1 acs",
    "period": "all",
    "in": "Evening"
}, {
    "product": "CLINISod",
    "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
    "dose": "2 cs",
    "period": "all",
    "in": "Morning"
}, {
    "product": "CLINISod",
    "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
    "dose": "1 cs",
    "period": "all",
    "in": "Evening"
}];
```

So, I want to get `dose` key which has `quantity + unit` but response using jQuery I want to get result
e.g. - 3 Acs , 3 cs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** to iterate over array of objects and create and object to store result.

```
// An object to store the result
var result = {};

// Iterate over array of objects
arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    // Extract quantity & unit
    var quantity = parseInt(obj.dose.match(/\d+/)[0], 10),
        unit = obj.dose.replace(/\d+/, '').trim();

    // If the unit already exists in the result object
    //    Add the quantity to it
    // else
    //    Store the quantity
    result[unit] = result[unit] ? result[unit] + quantity : quantity;
});
```

```js
var arr = [{
    "product": "CLINISod",
    "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
    "dose": "2 acs",
    "period": "all",
    "in": "Morning"
}, {
    "product": "CLINISod",
    "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
    "dose": "1 acs",
    "period": "all",
    "in": "Evening"
}, {
    "product": "CLINISod",
    "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
    "dose": "2 cs",
    "period": "all",
    "in": "Morning"
}, {
    "product": "CLINISod",
    "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
    "dose": "1 cs",
    "period": "all",
    "in": "Evening"
}];

var result = {};
arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    var quantity = parseInt(obj.dose.match(/\d+/)[0], 10),
        unit = obj.dose.replace(/\d+/, '').trim();
    result[unit] = result[unit] ? result[unit] + quantity : quantity;
});

console.log(result);
```

Above code will give the result in the object format, if you want it in array format just add

```
Object.keys(result).map(key => result[key] + ' ' + key)
```

at the bottom of the code.

```js
var arr = [{
    "product": "CLINISod",
    "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
    "dose": "2 acs",
    "period": "all",
    "in": "Morning"
}, {
    "product": "CLINISod",
    "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
    "dose": "1 acs",
    "period": "all",
    "in": "Evening"
}, {
    "product": "CLINISod",
    "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
    "dose": "2 cs",
    "period": "all",
    "in": "Morning"
}, {
    "product": "CLINISod",
    "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
    "dose": "1 cs",
    "period": "all",
    "in": "Evening"
}];

var result = {};
arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    var quantity = parseInt(obj.dose.match(/\d+/)[0], 10),
        unit = obj.dose.replace(/\d+/, '').trim();
    result[unit] = result[unit] ? result[unit] + quantity : quantity;
});

var arr = Object.keys(result).map(key => result[key] + ' ' + key);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: its funny, the accepted answer gives an object while OP asked for array. you're using regex twice for a simple function. and you are defining the regex every time inside the foreach which is a HUGE overhead. but yet its the accepted answer.

Comment: @AhmadBamieh OP didn't ask for array explicitly, and IMO object is best way for such operations. Also, OP has accepted answer which means this is what he wants.

Comment: he asked for something like 3 Acs , 3 cs. pretty much an array to me. and OP is clueless about JS and performance penalties of such code.

Comment: @AhmadBamieh To get an array, add [`Object.keys(result).map(key => result[key] + ' ' + key)`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/5Lz9vkea/) at the end of the above code. I've also updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery on this one, just use JSON.parse:

```
var response; // This is your json string from server.
var responseObject = JSON.parse(response);
// Get the keys with responseObject[i].dose, where i = the index in the array, i.e:
console.log(responseObject[0].dose); // prints "2 acs"
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants _I want to get result e.g. - 3 Acs , 3 cs_

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code. Hope this will help you.

```
var list = [
 {
   "product": "CLINISod",
   "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
   "dose": "2 acs",
   "period": "all",
   "in":"Morning"
 },      
 {
  "product": "CLINISod",
  "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
  "dose": "1 acs",
  "period": "all",
  "in":"Evening"
 },      
 {
  "product": "CLINISod",
  "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
  "dose": "2 cs",
  "period": "all",
  "in":"Morning"
 },
 {
  "product": "CLINISod",
  "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
  "dose": "1 cs",
  "period": "all",
  "in":"Evening"
 }
 ];



var acsSum = 0;
var csSum = 0;

$.each(Object.keys(list), function(index,value){

if(list[index].dose.indexOf("acs") != -1)
{

  acsSum = acsSum + Number(list[index].dose.split(" ")[0]);
}
else
{
  csSum = csSum + Number(list[index].dose.split(" ")[0]);
}

});
console.log(acsSum + " acs");
console.log(csSum + " cs");
```

Result of console.log-1 :3 acs
Result of console.log-2 :3 cs

Comment: Thanks but I want 2acs + 1acs = 3acs & 2cs + 1cs = 3cs .

Comment: indexOf lookups are more costly than using a hash map then assembling your array. you can check jsprefs or just think about it twice as well.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var rawData = [{
    "product": "CLINISod",
    "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
    "dose": "2 acs",
    "period": "all",
    "in": "Morning"
}, {
    "product": "CLINISod",
    "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
    "dose": "1 acs",
    "period": "all",
    "in": "Evening"
}, {
    "product": "CLINISod",
    "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
    "dose": "2 cs",
    "period": "all",
    "in": "Morning"
}, {
    "product": "CLINISod",
    "potentiation": "BIOLOGICALLY ACTIVE",
    "dose": "1 cs",
    "period": "all",
    "in": "Evening"
}];

var objectHash = {};
rawData.forEach(function(product) {
  var breakdown = product.dose.split(' ');
  var unit = breakdown[1];
  var quantity = Number(breakdown[0]);
  objectHash[unit] = objectHash[unit] || 0;
  objectHash[unit] += quantity;
});

function converToArray(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return obj[key] + ' ' + key;
  })
}

var results = converToArray(objectHash);
console.log(results);
```